# How to access the array dictionary values from mutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

how to get value from array of dictionary of key value array.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
listMutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:@"kiran",@"1234512345",@"IN", nil] forKey:[NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"phone",@"location", nil]],nil];
}
```

// set value to tableview cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// Custom cell declaration completed.
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
       NSLog(@"Value of name %@", [[listMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

when print the name key pair from the dictionary array from the mutable array which return nil object.

how to get name phone location values from the mutable array.

Comment: Did you log `listMutableArray` just to understand its structure? Because it seems to me that's it's not the one that you are expecting. For instance, your first object which is a dictionary has only ONE key and ONE value. `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` instead of `dictionaryWithObject:forKey:` ;)

Comment: @larme My first object which do have multiple key and multiple value.  I loged it its return key pair value too.  unable to get value from it.  {
        (
        name,
        phone,
        location
    ) =     (
        kiran,
        1234567890,
        IN
    );
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array formation is wrong Form array like this

```
NSMutableArray *listMutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"kiran",@"name",@"1234512345",@"phone",@"IN",@"location", nil], nil];

NSLog(@"%@",listMutableArray);
```

And In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try to print

```
NSLog(@"Value of name %@", [[listMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

You want to add multiple Object in array flow the below code

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"name": @"kiran",
                       @"phone": @"1234512345",
                       @"location": @"IN"
                       };

NSDictionary *dict1 = @{
                       @"name": @"Bala",
                       @"phone": @"12345123",
                       @"location": @"OUT"
                       };

NSDictionary *dict2 = @{
                       @"name": @"Sri",
                       @"phone": @"898989898",
                       @"location": @"IN"
                       };

NSMutableArray *listMutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict,dict1,dict2, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating an array containing a single dictionary with an array as a key and value.  I think you want an array of dictionaries; for example:

```
listMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[listMutableArray addObject:@{
    @"name": @"kiran",
    @"phone": @"1234512345",
    @"location": @"IN"
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We get all NSDictionary response add in jsonResult(NSDictionary) and create globel (arrData)NSMutableArray.

arrData = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i =0; i < [jsonResult count]; i++)
    {
           NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
[arrData addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[jsonResult valueForKey:string] valueForKey:@"name"],@"name",[[jsonResult valueForKey:string] valueForKey:@"phone"],@"phone",[[jsonResult valueForKey:string] valueForKey:@"location"],@"location",nil]];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// Custom cell declaration completed.
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
    NSLog(@"Value of name %@", [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]);
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *dictionary = @[
                              @{
                                @"Source_lat": @"28.6287",
                                @"Source_lon": @"77.3208",
                                @"Detail":@{
                                            @"Address": @"NOIDA",
                                            @"Region": @"NCR",
                                           },
                                },
                              @{
                                  @"Source_lat": @"28.628454",
                                  @"Source_lon": @"77.376945",

                                  }

                             ];
```